# How to generate service listings for jax-rs cxf

Tags: service, cxf, jax-rs

I got wadl for all the services. Now I need to generate service listings to my web-app. How to configure that in my web-app. I already seen http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-description.html#JAXRSServicesDescription-ServicelistingsandWADLqueries but its little confusing. Can anyone simplify it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this `domain:port/context-path?_wadl`. I think this provides the list of services available.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

That will give you a page listing all your "Available SOAP services" and "Available RESTful services".

For more information, please see http://cxf.apache.org/docs/servlet-transport.html